# bash Execute command after another one finishes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I have a list of files and my small program called `app`.
My list is `file01.txt` to `file1000.txt`.
I want to create a bash script that runs one by one:

```
app -i list01.txt     # to the file1000.txt
```

I want to execute the commands one by one, when the previous command finishes. Am I doing it in the right way in my example?

```
#!/bin/bash
app -i list01.txt;
app -i list02.txt;
app -i list03.txt;
```

Comment: Yes that should work - assuming `app` runs synchronously and does not daemonise itself. Though if you have many files or want that to be dynamic then it is better to use a loop and generate the file names dynamically.

Comment: Maybe you could do it in a loop for all files with something like `for f in list*.txt; do app -i "$f"; done`.

Comment: So, it's only the single digit numbers that get padded with one extra zero?

Comment: what about the output  I'm wondering if  output would be the same file can i use $RANDOM like for f in list*.txt; do app -i "$f -o $RANDOM.csv"; done

Comment: Maybe a job for `xargs`?

Answer (score 2):

If your app is running in standard foreground CLI (terminal) mode, you are right. This way, everything runs one by one, top to bottom.

Another way to run `app2` only after `app1` is as follows:

```
app1 && app2
```

Comment: thank you, yes i compile my code written in go to binary file using makefile 
build-linux:
 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o bin/app.linux-amd64 *.go

Comment: Yes. Then you are right, what you wrote will go top to bottom, no surprises.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `seq` to generate all the commands:

```sh
seq -f 'echo app -i file%02.0f.txt' 1 1000 | sh
```

If the output looks right, remove the `echo`